# tensorflow c++ loading pbtxt

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have the following code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;
using namespace tensorflow::ops;

Session* session; // tensorflow session
Status status;  // tensorflow status

float get_prediction(Tensor a, Tensor b);

float get_prediction(Tensor a, Tensor b) {

  float prediction;
  vector<Tensor> outputs;

  // preparing input
  // TODO: Update this line
  std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {{"inputlayer/inputxplaceholder", a}, {"inputlayer/targetyplaceholder", b}};

  // getting prediction for test data
  // TODO: Update this line

  status = session->Run(inputs, {"output/pred"}, {}, &outputs);

  if (!status.ok()) {
    cout<<"Error@get_prediction: "<<status.ToString()<<"\n";
    return 1l;
  }

  prediction = outputs[0].scalar<float>()(0);

  return prediction;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  ifstream f;
  string line = "";
  string token = "";
  float temp = 0.0;
  int temp1 = 0;
  float matches = 0.0, accuracy = 0.0;
  int row_no=0, col_no=0;
  float prediction = 0.0, actual = 0.0;

  status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  GraphDef graph_def;

  status = ReadTextProto(Env::Default(), "/home/usr/vector/res/usr/tensorflow/tensorflow/loader/mlp-32-1001.pbtxt", &graph_def);

  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  status = session->Create(graph_def);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  session->Run({}, {}, {"init_all_vars_op"}, nullptr);

  auto inputX = Tensor(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1,14}));
  auto inputY = Tensor(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1}));

  f.open("/home/usr/vector/res/usr/tensorflow/tensorflow/loader/signals_p.csv"); //processed csv

  getline(f,line);

  while(getline(f, line)) {

    /*if (row_no == 0) {
        row_no += 1;
        continue;
    }*/

    istringstream iss(line);

    while(getline(iss, token, ',')) {

      // filling feature tensors
      if((col_no >= 3 && col_no <= 14) || col_no == 21 || col_no == 22) {
        temp = stod(token.c_str());
        int index;
        if (col_no >= 3 && col_no <= 14)
          index = col_no - 3;
        else if (col_no == 21)
          index = 12;
        else
          index = 13;
        inputX.matrix<float>()(0,index) = temp;
      }

      // filling label tensor
      if(col_no == 16) {
        temp1 = stof(token.c_str());
        actual = temp1;
        inputY.vec<float>()(0) = temp1;
      }

      col_no += 1;

   }

    col_no = 0;
    row_no += 1;

    // getting prediction
    prediction = get_prediction(inputX, inputY);

    // if actual and prediction matches, increment matches
    if(actual == prediction)
      matches += 1;
  }

  accuracy = matches / (row_no);
  cout<<"Total Rows: "<<(row_no)<<endl;
  cout<<"Accuracy: "<<accuracy<<endl;

  //session->Close();
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error below:

```
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/bias
     [[{{node output/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value output/weight
     [[{{node output/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](output/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
     [[{{node hlayer01/bias/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/bias)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/weight
     [[{{node hlayer01/weight/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](hlayer01/weight)]]
Error@get_prediction: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value hlayer01/bias
```

Do I need to load the checkpoints? Am I doing something else wrong? The errors below are coming from the nodes in my .pbtxt file and I can tell they have not been initialized but I thought that was what session->Run({}, {}, {"init_all_vars_op"}, nullptr); was for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - you need to load the checkpoint with the following code:

```
/* restore model from checkpoint, iff checkpoint is given */
  if (checkpoint_fn != "") {
    const std::string restore_op_name = graph_def.saver_def().restore_op_name();
    const std::string filename_tensor_name =
        graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name();

    tensorflow::Tensor filename_tensor(tensorflow::DT_STRING,
                                       tensorflow::TensorShape());
    filename_tensor.scalar<std::string>()() = checkpoint_fn;

    tensor_dict feed_dict = {{filename_tensor_name, filename_tensor}};
    status = sess->Run(feed_dict, {}, {restore_op_name}, nullptr);
    if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK()) return status;
  } 
  else {
    status = sess->Run({}, {}, {"init"}, nullptr);
    if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK()) return status;
  }
  return tensorflow::Status::OK();
```